# pscp and UTF-8 characters

Tags: linux, windows, putty, scp, utf-8

I'm having trouble copying files with UTF-8 characters using pscp on Windows. I'm using command line for that and following command:

```
chcp 65001
pscp -scp -p -pw {pass} -batch "user@remote_host:/Справочник/file.txt" "E:\Справочник\file.txt"
scp: E:/??????????/file.txt: Cannot create file
```

As shown I get `scp: E:/??????????/file.txt: Cannot create file` error. How can I transfer files with UTF-8 characters in their path?

Comment: Уберите из пути `?` Not use in path `?` `chcp 866`

Comment: I have to work with all characters, not only Cyrillic.

Comment: Use Lucida console fonts and `chcp 65001`

Answer (score 0):

Application registry setting UTF-8 font (example:`cmd`)

Use path to `pscp`

Way-1, powershell:

Application path, change `\` to `_`:

AppUTF8Font.ps1:

```
$app='.\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe'
SL HKCU:\Console;NI $app;SL $app

New-ItemProperty . FaceName -t STRING -va "Lucida Console"
New-ItemProperty . FontFamily -t DWORD -va 0x00000036
```

[image]

Need allow local powershell script:

```
powershell -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"
```

And run:

```
powershell .\AppUTF8Font.ps1
```

Way-2, reg-file:

Or use reg-file:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe]
"FaceName"="Lucida Console"
"FontFamily"=dword:00000036
```

Command line:

```
REG IMPORT Cmd_UTF8.reg
```

Delete setting reg-file:

```
REGEDIT4

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe]
```

Command line:

```
REG IMPORT Cmd_UTF8_Delete.reg
```